# YUI2 setStyle opacity not working in IE10

Tags: yui, internet-explorer-10, yui2

I have some YUI2 code (v2.8.1) that looks like this:

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('foo', 'opacity', 0.5);
```

and:

```
var t = new YAHOO.util.Anim(this._splashSlide.shutter, {opacity: {from: 1.0, to: 0}}, 1, YAHOO.util.Easing.easeBoth);
```

It has been working fine for a number of years and it automatically decides whether it can use `style.opacity` or whether (for IE) it has to use the IE `style.filter` to achieve opacity.  For a variety of reasons, it is not worth porting this code to YUI3.

Along comes IE 10, which (in standards mode) no longer has the `style.filter` property and only supports the standard `style.opacity` property.  That's all good, but the YUI2 version I'm running against doesn't know about IE 10 and is apparently still using the `style.filter` property which no longer works.

So, my question is whether there is an update to YUI2 that is IE10 compatible and uses the `opacity` property for IE versions where that property exists?

If it was just a simple style setting, I could work around it, but I have a number of YUI animations and I can't find an easy way to work around those (nor do I want to spend the time doing so).

Has Yahoo fixed this for YUI2?  Anyone aware of a work-around, particularly for the animation functions that call `YD.setStyle()` internally?

Comment: YUI 2 has been in maintenance-only mode since 2009 (when YUI 3 was released), so it will not be seeing any new development to support IE10.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found an answer to my own question.  YUI2 v2.9.0 changes their `setStyle()` function to use feature detection so they now properly use `style.opacity` on browsers that support it and only use IE's `style.filter` when `style.opacity` is not supported.

If ever one wanted a poster child for why browser detection is bad and feature detection is good, this is a perfect example.  Because YUI2 originally used browser detection, it is now broken on IE10.  If they had used feature detection in the first place, the older versions of YUI2 would work on IE10 without requiring an update.

Now, to see if I can get the site where my code runs to upgrade to YUI v2.9.0.  If not, I'll have to code a messy workaround.